# require files in vue-javascript, how is it possible?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, node-modules

I would like to embed mathematical notation from strings read from a JSON file.
This apparently works great as seen [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/testing-vue3-markdown-it-markdown-it-texmath-iqgi6?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue), where I also took this screenshot:

[image]

Of course it doesn't work on my machine. I get `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: require is not defined`, as expected.

I once learned `require('X')` is for node.js context, whereas `import { X } from 'Y'` is for browser context or .vue files.

I already tried to remove

`"type": "module"`

from package.json, but it didn't change a thing.

Can someone explain?

Is there a rule, to when to use require instead of import in 'frontend js'?

I read an article where I was told to remove

`"type": "module"`

from package.json, but it didn't change a thing.

Comment: Did you check the docs first? They show the usage of ES modules https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-it#usage-examples . The question doesn't make sense in general as this is specific to the environment where you use Vue, not Vue itself.

Comment: "...specific to the environment where you use Vue, not Vue itself" elaborate please

Comment: In your environment you should use the import syntax. There are several examples on the page linked above.

Comment: There are several ways to use Vue, see https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start and https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/tooling.html . You'll get require() with webpack-based tools (Vue CLI) but not other ways. The use of require() in an example most time means it's node.js code

Comment: I can see "Header" only not "mathematical notation" in [there](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/testing-vue3-markdown-it-markdown-it-texmath-iqgi6?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue) Can you  capture "mathematical notation" example in your question?

Comment: @BenchVue I mean LaTeX (or katex or whatever), that's not the point of the question, sorry for misdirection, the library is there, it is only about importing/requiring

Comment: Do you want to source code example LaTeX for Vue 3.0 JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In modern JavaScript development, especially in the context of using frameworks like Vue.js or when working with build tools like Webpack, Rollup, or Vite, you typically use the ES module syntax (import/export) instead of the CommonJS syntax (require).

The require function is not natively supported in browsers; it is specific to Node.js for importing modules. On the other hand, the ES module syntax (import/export) is supported in modern browsers and is the standard way to include modules in your front-end JavaScript code.

Here's why you might see require being used and how you should handle modules in different contexts:

Node.js Environment:
In a Node.js environment, require is used to import modules. If you're working on a server-side application or a build process with Node.js, require is appropriate.

Bundlers and Transpilers:
When using a bundler like Webpack or a transpiler like Babel, you can use require in your source code, and the tool will transform it into code that works in the browser. These tools bundle up all your dependencies into one or more JavaScript files that the browser can understand.

Front-End JavaScript:
For front-end code that will run in the browser, especially if you're not using a bundler, you should use the import statement to include ES modules.

Vue.js Single File Components:
Inside Vue.js single-file components (.vue files), you should use the import statement to include other modules or components.

Module Type:
The "type": "module" field in package.json indicates that your JavaScript files are using ES module syntax. If you're not seeing require working, it could be because the environment expects import statements due to this field.

Based on your screenshot, here's how you could adjust your code to use ES modules:

```js
// Importing the modules using ES module syntax
import MarkdownIt from 'markdown-it';
import MarkdownItTexmath from 'markdown-it-texmath';
import katex from 'katex';

export function register() {
  // Use the modules
  const md = MarkdownIt().use(MarkdownItTexmath, {
    engine: katex,
    delimiters: 'dollars',
  });

  // Other code...
}
```

Make sure to install the necessary packages using npm or yarn, and then you can import them as shown above. If you're using a bundler, it will handle the conversion and packaging of these modules for browser compatibility.

If you're directly writing scripts for inclusion in a browser without a build step, and you want to use modules, you need to include the script with type="module" and use import statements. Here's an example of how to do this in an HTML file:

```js
<script type="module">
  import { register } from './your-script.js';
  // Call your function or do other work with the imported module
</script>
```

Remember to replace './your-script.js' with the actual path to your JavaScript file.

Comment: Thank you so much. Great, for my purposes complete answer. 
Let me be honest, I'm using Electron, Vite and Vue and I am fairly new to Node.js. My issue was you can "require" a complete module into a variable, but need to "import" _specific_ stuff from a module. I got it mixed up and frustrated quickly.